# Grab first address segment from google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Ideally using the Google API and not a Javascript hack to grab everything before the comma, I was wondering if it is possible to grab the first bit of the address in a box. This is the code I'm using:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xw4ZM/3/

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize(){
//MAP
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.659,-4.714);
  var options = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

}

$(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
  });

  //Add listener to marker for reverse geocoding
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
          $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
          $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

This is the scenaio I am trying to achieve, if the user enters this:

```
Swindon, Wiltshire, United Kingdom
The "name" value is this: "Swindon"

Wiltshire, United Kingdom:
The "name" value is this "Wiltshire"

United Kingdom:
The "name" value is this "United Kingdom"
```

It is basically saving the most accurate location supplied in the name field, whether it is the town, city, county or country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it could help you in your situation, but there are address components in the address search result object.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

```
geocoder.geocode({
        'address': request.term
    }, function (results, status) {
        for (i in results) {
            var result = results[i];

            for (j in result.address_components) {
                var segment = result.address_components[j];

                // do something with address segment
            }
        }
    })
```

or

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': request.term
}, function (results, status) {
    $.each(results, function (i, result) {
        $.each(result.address_components, function (i, segment) {
            // do something with address segment
        });
    });
})
```